# Audience information for a twitter handle

Tags: twitter, python-requests, audience

Sorry if my question to too naive. But i wish to find audience level information for a particular twitter handle. Lets consider @BarackObama, i wish to find his followers by gender, age, language, location etc. I used python scripts in this link https://github.com/GnipDz/Python-Insights to achieve it.

I do have access to twitter ADS API but it still shows your application ID is not authorized when i try to run the scripts. Is there a special API or addition over Ads API to achieve this? can someone guide me as to how i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those scripts use Twitter's enterprise (commercial) Audience API. This API does not enable you to access audiences for individual users, only aggregated data for large numbers of Twitter handles. Additionally, this is not a free-to-access API so you need to have an active enterprise subscription for this to work.

I'm not aware of any programmatic way to access this data, and particularly not for any organic account - the Engagement API enables access to Tweet engagements for the authenticated account, but you're not able to access that data for other users.

Comment: Hi Andy.. Thank you. This helps a lot.. But what exactly do you mean by large number of twitter handles? If i understand correctly, you cannot use this API to access organic accounts like BarackObama. But can you use this to get information about twitter accounts of brands like McDonalds ?

Comment: You'd have to pass in a large number of handles (500 or more) to created the audience segment, at which point you can get back some demographic data in percentages. You will not get back individual user handles.